# HTML from Adobe Animate (formerly Flash) - Sprite Sheet causes problems in specific browsers

Tags: html, animation, browser, banner, sprite-sheet

all! Experienced animator, but very new to programming, so every baby step is an exciting new roadblock. I've been hired to create/animate some HTML web banners, and am using Adobe Animate.

In order to keep my file sizes down, I have my publishing settings set to combine images into a sprite sheet. This seems to work fine when I test the HTML in Firefox, but when I test it in any other browser, I just see a blank background. Forgoing the sprite sheet solves the problem, but bloats my k-weight. I've tried setting the sprite sheet to PNG-8, PNG-24, and PNG-32, and the error persists.

I'm not sure if this additional info makes a difference, but clicking in the blank background doesn't activate the link, so the images aren't simply "invisible".

Thank you in advance, everyone!

Edit 1: Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>File_Camper2_size300x250_v6</title>
<!-- write your code here -->


<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="File_Camper2_size300x250_v6.js?1466448165331"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;
function init() {
    // --- write your JS code here ---

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};
    ss = ss||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadFile({src:"images/File_Camper2_size300x250_v6_atlas_.json?1466448165331", type:"spritesheet", id:"File_Camper2_size300x250_v6_atlas_"}, true);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
    var queue = evt.target;
    ss["File_Camper2_size300x250_v6_atlas_"] = queue.getResult("File_Camper2_size300x250_v6_atlas_");
    exportRoot = new lib.File_Camper2_size300x250_v6();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();
    stage.enableMouseOver();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

</script>

<!-- write your code here -->

</head>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4;margin:0px;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2: The following console errors appear in Google Chrome, indicating the json error mentioned below.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/jonron2000/Documents/Company%20Name/Ice%20Cream%20Summer/Revamped/v6/images/File_size300x250_v6_atlas_.json?1466448165331. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.b.load @ createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:15
createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:13

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNumFrames' of undefinedb.load @ createjs-2015.11.26.min.js:15

Comment: To get any help it is better to post the HTML, otherwise it is not a  stackoverflow question

Comment: Thank you, I've added the HTML. Pretty important, I imagine.

Comment: How are you testing? SpriteSheets require a JSON file to be loaded, which will not work on a local file:/// URI in most browsers. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm testing by simply opening the html file in the given browsers (Safari and Chrome in thsi case). Adobe Animate does automatically create the JSON file, and yes, there are errors in the console, which I will post now in the original question.